# What is the simplest way to wait for user input during an interactive pyplot plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

It seems that there are many ways to do one thing in `matplotlib.pyplot`. Sometimes, I want to put together a plot where I want to think about the current step before plotting the next one. E. g.,

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = [x/10 for x in range(-5, 6)]
Y = [x**2 for x in X]

for x, y in zip(X, Y):
    plt.plot([x], [y], 'k.')
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.2)
    # input('Continue? ')  # ------- (1)
```

This is a quick and perhaps a dirty way of doing it. Now, if I want to wait a bit more during some iterations and then quickly allow a couple, I can uncomment line (1).

Is there a way I can add a button or something to the plot GUI itself without rearranging everything?  I know of one way where you do event handlers and all, but I can never remember how. So really, if possible, I want to be able to add a couple lines to the code listing above and accomplish what I want.